# how to display data from DB on the .append input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

i have a button that creates a new input field and a default field

```
<div class="container1">
   <button class="add_form_field">Add Title</button>
   <div class="form-group label-floating">
      <input type="text" id="title_name">
   </div>
</div>
```

and this is the jquery that creates a new input field.

```
var max_fields      = 10;
var wrapper         = $(".container1"); 
var add_button      = $(".add_form_field"); 

var x = 1; 
$(add_button).click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ 
        x++; 
        $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" id="title_name"/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
else
{
alert('You Reached the limits')
}
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".delete", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
});
```

and i have ajax call to get the title name from my database based on the user logged in.

```
$.ajax({
        url:'../ajax/getprofile.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{userid:user},
        dataType:'JSON',
        success: function(result){
        $('#title_name').val(result.title_name);
        }
});
```

when i use `console.log(result)` to see what the data is being returned what happen is that only one data is being returned from my ajax request..[image]

i just didn't include the other data on my question earlier cuz those data only return one data.. i only have problem with the title_name

this code works fine for only the default input field.. like the data from my database only shows up on the default input field not on the appended input field..

saying i have a user id of 10001 and my db is look like this
**tbl_title**

```
id    |   name
10001 | sample
10001 | test
```

what i want to achieve is that when i make a request from ajax and returned the requested value it will display on my input field.and since my id is similar to the tbl_title (id) it should display the two data on the input field. but unfortunately only the 1st data is being displayed only on the default input field what i wanted to make is that if the data is more than 1 it will also display on the appended input field.. but i dont have any idea how this works..

b4 i only got one data that is being returned so i updated my mysql to return all the data that have similar id so now i got `array1` and `array2` array1 is on the picture and the array2 is similar to the picture but the only difference is their title_name.. so what should i do to display my the two title_name on the array on my input field

Comment: 2 elements cannot have the same ID. An ID should **always** be unique. The browser assumes there is only one element with the found ID and sets the data in the first one. Also, what we dont know is, whats the structure of the response of the AJAX request when it has both data?

Comment: i check it and only one is being returned. even though i have two `title_name` that have the same id and my mysql query displays two data.

Comment: Make sure you serialize the SQL query result to JSON format and echo it back to the requesting page

Comment: after the ajax request the returned data is `json_encode` but i dont know why but the only one data is being returned..

Comment: It returns probably all but your jQuery selector only select the first (because of the id) ...

Answer (score 0):

The id is the same for each input. So jQuery takes the first catch in this line:

```
$('#title_name').val(result.title_name);
```

Thats why only the first input works ...

Try to change it something like this:

```
$(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" id="input_' + x + '"/> ...
```

and:

```
$('#input' + x ).val(result.title_name);
```

Probably not exactly right but a push in the right direction ;) The id is the problem.

Comment: Yeah with your information i can't give you a complete working snippet. I don't know in wich context your ajax is and what it returns. The problem is that you targeting all inputs and jquery delivers the first (because of the id) ... Probably you have to use a class and on ajax success something like jQuery('.class').each or iterate trough your returns ...

Comment: when i tried changing the` $('#title_name'+x).val(result.title_name);` and the append base on your suggestion it seems that my ajax only targets the default input field not the appended input field.. cuz after replacing i reload the page and the data is not being displayed on the default inputfield.

Comment: Yeah sorry thats probably the false approach cause you have no loop in your ajax. Completely remove the id ... you want to select multiple inputs so this wont be helpful (most likely). Can you update you question so that we can see what your ajax is returning as result?

Comment: Ok there are two problems here ... You should iterate through your results in some way. But getprofile.php doesn't seems to return return multiple entries ... you have to fix that first before your javascript-sided-part can do anything right

Comment: Well then let is know what was the problem